# jQuery variable loop with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, loops

I have multiple ajax buttons in a page that I would like each one to send a GET data to a php file. Data are stored in HTML attributes. Here's what I have:

**EDIT:** full codes inserted (document ready)

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
var IDR = $('.ajax').attr("id");    

    var rtitle = $("#"+IDR).attr("name-title");


                console.log(rtitle);
                console.log(IDR);

                // ajax report
                $(".ajax").colorbox({
                    width: '670px',
                    data: "rtitle="+ rtitle
                });

                return false;
      });
 });
```

The thing is it's sending the GET data only for the first button..

Example from HTML:

```
<li><a title="" data-original-title="" href="report.php" class="ajax cboxElement" name-title="RTITILE 1" id="3829"> Report</a></li>
<li><a title="" data-original-title="" href="report.php" class="ajax cboxElement" name-title="RTITLE 2" id="3830"> Report</a></li>
```

**EDIT:** I'm using the [jQuery Colorbox plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) ajax properties which works the same as the jQuery load().

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to do a `.each()` loop?  I have no idea how your ajax is working.  But it sounds like you need to do a `$('.ajax').each()` loop

Comment: Could you provide at least the full code **block**?

Comment: @ChritianGartner you mean the Javascript code?

Comment: Yes and your edit was exactly what I meant :D

Comment: What's interesting is that `var IDR = $('.ajax').attr('id');` and `$('#' + IDR)` means you've got elements in your page that have **duplicate IDs**. That, or you're selecting the same element (in what is kind of a redundant process).

Comment: @RichardNeilllagan There are no duplicate IDs in the page, the ajax was working fine, the problem was in the Colorbox jQuery plugin. Or in other words the problem was mine because I wanted to send data via the `load()` function with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the buttons with class `ajax`

**Otherwise it would only select the first instance found.**

Also you need to `use $(this) context`

```
$.each($('.ajax'), function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    var IDR = $this.attr("id");
    var rtitle = $("#" + IDR).attr("name-title");
    console.log(rtitle);
    console.log(IDR);

    // ajax report
    $this.colorbox({
        width: '670px',
        data: "rtitle=" + rtitle
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this doesn't trigger ajax.

Comment: `$(".ajax").colorbox` should triger the ajax for any element with class "ajax". This is based on the jQuery Colorbox plugin. (Link posted in main question)